# Automatic button click not working in JSF

Tags: javascript, jsf, jsf-2

I at trying to pass values from a form a into my bean in JSF by calling the button in javaScript, but it isn't working for some reason. Please take a look:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core">

<head>
<title>Dropdown List</title>
</head>
<body>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
        <h:outputText value="#{helloWorld.getResultSet1()}" escape="false" />
        <f:attribute name="action" value="1" />
    </select>
    <br />

    <h:form id="formId">
        <h:inputHidden id="x" value="#{helloWorld.text}" />
        <h:commandButton id = "x1" value="submit" action="#{helloWorld.submit}" />
    </h:form>

    <select id="mySelect1">
    </select>

    <script>
        var x1 = document.getElementById("mySelect1");
        x1.style.display = 'none';

        function myFunction() {
            var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;

            document.getElementById("formId:x").value = x;
            document.getElementById("formId").submit();

            x1.style.display = 'block';

        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What could be causing the problem? Perhaps I did something wrong?

Comment: Please as commented in your other question and the answer there... _"This is really not the way to make dropdowns in JSF. I would recommend to read some JSF beginners guides, and even HTML beginners guides might help (for example, there is no <form> in your code)."_ Constructs like this only lead to more problems...

Comment: For this reason (sorry) I downvoted the question. This sort of code should not be used as an example anywhere... It is using jsf a very wrong way and 'circumventing' features that make jsf great. If others start implementing things this way, they need to add external libraries for csrf, adding additional code for putting validation messages and style on the right input and then start 'blaming/dissing' JSF while the error is on their side...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("formId").submit();
```

please use

```
document.getElementById("formId:x1").click();
```

to submit the form.

Comment: Care to explain why?

Comment: Yes sure. Since there is no action associated with the form tag, there is no point in triggering the submit event on form tag. Instead when triggering the click event on the button, the form is submitted and the associated backing bean method will be executed which is the expected scenario in this case.

Comment: @OTM: This question is **soooo** not 'jsf' that I'd not start to try to provide answers for the problem(s) encountered. OP will most likely run into new problems after this (unwanted security risks (crsf) that a good jsf solution prevents), returning good validation errors and more) And btw, the 'action' is added by JSF automagically (it is an `h:form` not a plain html form)

Comment: Sure. I did not think about that.